# Image gallery with html

Tags: html, image

Looking to make an image gallery (Tumblr style)(bunch of images) and be able to put text or an input button on them? I tried with  and place each of them but, when you resize the window, they may not fit anymore.
here is an example: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f166f9ee75444a16e55517850b35a79578ad5e65/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f33373371317633753359336433503177316530742f53637265656e25323053686f74253230323031332d30362d3033253230617425323031302e32332e3438253230414d2e706e67
I tried to place each picture like this `<img src="picture.jpg" weight="100" width="475"/>`.

Comment: Your question is far too broad, to unprecise to get a good answer. Try to ask more specific: what _exactly_ do you do (your code), and _exactly_ is the issue?

Comment: Which does not tell me anything about your code and issue...

Comment: I had something worked out but it was to place each image with weight and width but was sketchy. So, I am looking for an alternative

Comment: An alternative to _what_? Sorry, but if you do not ask a specific question, then it is impossible to answer. All you showed so far is some thumbnails in a grid. no code, no description of the markup, no style rules, nothing. Also it is unclear what you actually want to do. What text? Where is it? How is it meant to be?

Comment: I am looking a way to place pictures in order that they fit and I can resize them. If I make the screen bigger, they will move in order to fill the space. Then, I wish to be able to write code over the pictures (the pictures are in background)

Comment: OK, slowly we come closer. So the grid holding the images is just a concatenation of the image tags to flow naturally. Two alternatives I can see to place text above: 1. do not use image tags at all, but put the images as background to div tags which hold the text. That way the images are anchored to the text automatically. Or you use image tags and a pseudo element (`:after` or `:before`) to place the text. Using style rules you can relatively place that text on the image. Put the text into a data attribute of the image tag, then you can use the css `content` rule to pick it up per image.